# Linux and Windows Server Setup

Tags: linux, windows-server-2008, hyper-v, oracle, windows

I have an win 2008 R2 machine (a home machine of mine) that I am messing around with and learning the server technologies.  I also wanted to try out oracle, and was wondering if its possible to setup a LINUX machine with Oracle, and have the two interoperate.

What I mean by that is if I setup the server and my laptop on a domain, would it be possible to communicate to that LINUX machine and thus the Oracle database, and if so, are there any good resources on the setup?

I was going to create a LINUX hyper v virtual...

Any tips appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure.  You can host whatever you like in Hyper-V.  Communication would be done through networking.

In order to get networking going well in Linux under Hyper-V, you need the "Linux Integration Components, which can be downloaded from Microsoft.

Only certain distros are officially supported, but if your plan is to just mess around, most any distro should work.  Here's a link to the downloads:

https://connect.microsoft.com/site495

(These links tend to work only for a short time.  Use a search engine if it's broken by the time you read this.)